# MySQL 5.5.28 build errors

Tags: mysql

I use mingw-w64 (ruben build) on Windows 7 64.

I need libmysqlclient.a to build libodb-mysql (http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/). But in original Windows 64 mysql build there is no .a library (only mysqlclient.lib). Reimp does not work (generate a lot of files with different integer numbers in the names, but not .a library).

I am tying to build MySQL Community Server 5.5.28.

The command sequence:

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" .
make
```

I got

```
[ 11%] Building C object strings/CMakeFiles/strings.dir/ctype-mb.c.obj                                           
[ 11%] Building C object strings/CMakeFiles/strings.dir/ctype-simple.c.obj                                       
In file included from C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_sys.h:44:0,                          
                 from c:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/strings/ctype-simple.c:19:                      
C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_pthread.h:59:3: error: unknown type name 'CONDITION_VARIABL
E'                                                                                                               
C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_pthread.h:102:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timespec'  
In file included from d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/pro
cess.h:12:0,                                                                                                     
                 from C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_global.h:128,                        
                 from c:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/strings/ctype-simple.c:16:                      
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/types.h:89:8: note: o
riginally defined here                                                                                           
In file included from C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_sys.h:44:0,                          
                 from c:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/strings/ctype-simple.c:19:                      
C:/Users/CanisMajor/Downloads/mysql-5.5.28/include/my_pthread.h:715:5: error: unknown type name 'SRWLOCK'        
make[2]: *** [strings/CMakeFiles/strings.dir/ctype-simple.c.obj] Error 1                                         
make[1]: *** [strings/CMakeFiles/strings.dir/all] Error 2                                                        
mak

e: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Probably better for Serverfault

Comment: @MikeBrant: No, this is not a good fit for SF. It's a compilation error of a development tool on a client OS which is not something we deal with. Please consider just closing questions OT rather than migrating them in future although I can't see why this would be OT here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a compiler issue. Specifically, it is not recognizing some tokens, due to your compilation flags and definitions.

[CONDITION_VARIABLE in windows; wont compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872010/condition-variable-in-windows-wont-compile)