# Error compile "CONDITION_VARIABLE undeclared"

Tags: c++, windows, condition-variable

sorry for my bad english if it's bad.

my code

```
#include <windows.h>

int     main(void)
{
    CONDITION_VARIABLE      cond;

    return 0;
}
```

i have the following error when i compil.

```
CONDITION_VARIABLE undeclared
```

i have the same error than in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872010/condition-variable-in-windows-wont-compile/18564334#18564334), and i have seen in my Winbase.h file than i don't have the following typedef

```
typedef RTL_CONDITION_VARIABLE CONDITION_VARIABLE, *PCONDITION_VARIABLE;
```

i have found where i can to find a better Winbase.h, i have found this site

http://source.winehq.org/source/include/winbase.h

But i want to know if i can replace my current Winbase.h file with a simple copy past of content of this site ? or there is a better method please ?

Bye.

Comment: I would suggest not, since among other things, that file is not meant for windows, there might possibly be optimizations there for linux systems, etc, as unlikely as it is

Comment: Have you tried the answers on the other question?

Comment: i has try, yes it's a bad idea. On linux i know how to do this, but i need to do this in a cross platfrom program, so i need the code for linux (it's ok) and for windows (not ok).

Comment: Yes,  Karthik T, i have triedm but don't compil again, screen here http://imageshack.us/a/img202/9879/ur9o.jpg

Comment: What version of the Windows SDK are you using?  `CONDITION_VARIABLE` was added in Windows Vista.  It sounds like you are using an old Windows SDK.

Comment: Hello, i have the v8.0, i have looked in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows, and there are two directories v8.0 and v8.0A

Answer (score 2):

Support for `CONDITION_VARIABLE` was added in Windows Vista.  You are using an older version of the Windows SDK if `CONDITION_VARIABLE` is not declared in the headers.  Do not modify the SDK headers.  You will need to obtain a recent version of the SDK (e.g. the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx)).

Comment: Hello, thank you, but i'm on windows seven, can i use this version which is for windows 8 on my windows seven ?

Comment: Re, i have seen, Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, thank you i doing this update, i can't make +1 to you because i don't have the required réputation, sorry ^^.

Comment: i have finish the windows SDK update and the probleme isn't solved. i have used your link [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) download and install, stop my computer and reboot, but nothing. any idea ?

Comment: i'm trying again with [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx)

Comment: Ok sorry, it works, i have compiled my true project and it works, but my little test don't works, i don't know why, but it's does not matter, thank you again, good bye.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing this:

```
 #include <condition_variable>
```

Goodluck!

Comment: No.  `<condition_variable>` declares `std::condition_variable`, the C++11 condition variable type.  The Windows SDK (included via `<windows.h>`) declares `CONDITION_VARIABLE`, the Windows condition variable primitive.

Comment: Hello, with #include <condition_variable>, my compiler don't found the directory condition_variable. James McNellis in a comment above have said, than i need a better version of my windows SDK ? If it's the case, i have found this site web http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138 (i have windows seven), is that right ?

Comment: Thank you for your help user2685803 but i prefer work with CONDITION_VARIABLE.